# Android Tv Global search displaying app's content results with different params

Tags: android, android-tv

So I connected my app to the Global Search and everything is working great.

My problem is that in some devices the height and width of the Global search's results' card views are different and look more rectangular than square like in most devices what causes the images to not display fully.

I tried different ways to handle the results' params but with no success.

For other apps like youtube, it works well in both cases.

** Both cases happen on two Xiaomi 3 streamers with the same android version, kernal version etc.

**Update**

After checking 4 different devices 2 reproducing this issue and 2 not I found that the Android TV Core Services system app's and the Android TV Home system app's version are different for the two cases.

In versions f-1.12 it works fine in squares while in versions f-1.6 the views are rectangular.

Could this be related? And if yes than how to adress this issue to make is work on both ends?

Is there any way to manage the displayed params?

Square images -

[image: Square images]

Rectangle images -

[image: Rectangle images]

My implementation for any seekers -

Manifest declaration (Search intent Activity and ContentProvider) -

```
<application
 // ......
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.SearchSuggestionActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">

        <!-- Receives the search request. -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            <!-- No category needed, because the Intent will specify this class component -->
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- Points to searchable meta data. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
// ......
</application>
```

ContentProvider -

```
public class AppContentProvider extends ContentProvider {

    private static final String AUTHORITY = "com.your.package.provider";

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        return true;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Cursor query(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable String[] projection, @Nullable String selection, String[] selectionArgs, @Nullable String sortOrder) {
        if (selectionArgs == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "selectionArgs must be provided for the Uri: " + uri);
        }

        //... do API calls if required...

        return getSuggestions(selectionArgs[0]);
    }

    private Cursor getSuggestions(String query) {

        query = query.toLowerCase();
        String[] columns = new String[]{
                KEY_ID,
                KEY_NAME,
                KEY_DESCRIPTION,
                KEY_IMAGE,
                KEY_DATA,

        };
        return getWordMatch(query, columns);
    }

    private Cursor getWordMatch(String query, String[] columns) {
        // implemented with MatrixCursor because I first fetch from api and than build the row instead of fetching a Curser directly from DB 
        MatrixCursor matrixCursor = new MatrixCursor(columns, columns.length);

        //... some data building code ...

        String[] searchResultMap = new String[]{
                String.valueOf(searchResult.getVodId()),
                searchResult.getTitle(),
                searchResult.getDescription(),
                url,
                assetToSend.toString() // Here send a Json of the search result object to fetch at SearchSuggestionActivity (this is basically SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_EXTRA_DATA's column)
        };

        matrixCursor.addRow(searchResultMap);

        return matrixCursor;
    }

    public class SearchContentTableConsts {
        //The columns we'll include in the video database table
        static final String KEY_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
        static final String KEY_NAME = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1;
        static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2;
        static final String KEY_IMAGE = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_RESULT_CARD_IMAGE;
        static final String KEY_DATA = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_EXTRA_DATA;
    }

}
```

searchable xml -

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/search_label"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:searchSettingsDescription="@string/search_label"
    android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.your.package.provider"
    android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.intent.action.VIEW"
    android:searchSuggestIntentData="content://com.your.package.provider/search_suggest_query"
    android:searchSuggestSelection="MATCH ?"
    android:searchSuggestThreshold="1"
    android:includeInGlobalSearch="true">
</searchable>
```

In the SearchSuggestionActivity just get the data from the intent's extra -

```
public class SearchSuggestionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String TAG = SearchSuggestionActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getIntent().getExtras() == null) {
            finish();
        }

        catchSearchAssetInfo();
    }

    private void catchSearchAssetInfo() {
        String searchResultJson = getIntent().getExtras().getString(SearchManager.EXTRA_DATA_KEY);

        JSONObject jsonObject;
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(searchResultJson);
            // Create your data from the jsonObject

        } catch (JSONException err) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error - " + err.toString());
        }

        proceedToAsset();
    }

    private void proceedToAsset() {
        // Open result page for example
    }

}
```

I would really appreciate any lead on this issue.

Comment: Same here. Have you find the solution?